# Find most common data values from MySQL columns?

Tags: php, mysql, autosuggest

I'm trying to integrate a music suggestion application in to my current music rating application. And I was looking for a way to suggest music, based on current tastes.

I'm writing this question on my iPod, so the formatting is probably wrong, so I'll explain the columns.

`rate_id`, `username`, `artist`, `type` (male/female/mix), `song_id`, `songname`, `genre`, `year`, `like`, `dislike`

For example, one person likes 4 tracks, this query being:

```sql
SELECT * FROM rates WHERE username='$_SESSION['username']' LIMIT 4 ORDER BY id
```

returns:

```
1   | mrexample | Katy Perry    | F | 55 | Firework     | Pop | 2010 | 1 | 0
78  | mrexample | Lady Gaga     | F | 36 | Pokerface    | Pop | 2010 | 1 | 0
95  | mrexample | Nelly         | F | 96 | Just a Dream | Pop | 2010 | 1 | 0
106 | mrexample | Justin Bieber | M | 78 | Baby         | Pop | 2010 | 1 | 0
```

Ok, so from that pattern of rating, we know that mrexample mostly liked pop songs by females, written in 2010, so from that data, we form a query to our user generated music collection database:

```php
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM music WHERE genre='pop' AND type='F' AND year='2010' LIMIT 5 ORDER BY RAND()")
```

Now, my question is: **how do I find out what that common data is from a large chunk of data about that person's rates?**

I'm thinking there has to be a mysql command for it, but I'm not sure :/

I thought about if statements, impossible, too many possibilities if part of the popular part was the artist, loads of artists are in our db. switch, same thing again. count, nothing in particular that I can count. I could mysql num rows against if's, again - too much to handle.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you are looking at is a custom requirement of your application. You need to decide what "popular" means to you and write an algorithm based on the parameters you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This query gives you user's favorite genre. If you want to count in other parameters like 'type' you need to define a formula for that and change this query accordingly.

```
SELECT genre FROM rates
  WHERE username = '$_SESSION["username"]'
  GROUP BY genre
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot all about the grouping! (new to php/SQL) :)

Answer (score 0):

At a trivial level....

```
SELECT type, genre, year, (SUM(like)-SUM(dislike))/COUNT(*)
FROM rates
WHERE username='$escaped_username'
GROUP BY type, genre, year
ORDER BY (SUM(like)-SUM(dislike))/COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```

But you might you want to allow for cases where there's no great difference between, say particular years....

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT type, genre, year, (SUM(like)-SUM(dislike))/COUNT(*) as pref
FROM rates
WHERE username='$escaped_username'
GROUP BY type, genre, year
UNION
SELECT type, genre, '%', (SUM(like)-SUM(dislike))/COUNT(*) as pref
FROM rates
WHERE username='$escaped_username'
GROUP BY type, genre
) ilv
ORDER BY ilv.pref DESC;
```

And because there are 3 different fields - that's 6 subqueries you'd need to write for any combination of type/genre/year.

Note that neither of the above would give the same result as....

```
SELECT r.type, r.genre, r.year, artist, song_id, song_name
FROM rates r,
(SELECT type as preftype FROM rates t WHERE username='$escaped_username' 
   GROUP BY type ORDER BY (SUM(like)-SUM(dislike))/COUNT(*) DESC
   LIMIT 0,1) as pref_type,
(SELECT genre as prefgenre FROM rates g WHERE username='$escaped_username' 
   GROUP BY genre ORDER BY (SUM(like)-SUM(dislike))/COUNT(*) DESC
   LIMIT 0,1) as pref_genre,
(SELECT year as prefyear FROM rates y WHERE username='$escaped_username' 
   GROUP BY year ORDER BY (SUM(like)-SUM(dislike))/COUNT(*) DESC
   LIMIT 0,1) as pref_year
WHERE r.type=preftype
AND r.genre=prefgenre
AND r.year=prefyear
AND username='$escaped_username'
ORDER BY likes DESC, dislikes ASC
```